# Composer Install .tar.gz

Tags: tar, gzip, composer

Trying to install node.js via composer (for automation).

```
"repositories": [
  "type": "package",
    "package": {
        "name": "nodejs/nodejs",
        "version": "0.12.6",
        "dist": {
        "type": "gzip",
        "url": "https://nodejs.org/dist/v0.12.6/node-v0.12.6-linux-x64.tar.gz"
      }
    }
  }
],
"require": {
  "nodejs/nodejs": "0.12.*"
}
```

Problem is, I can either use `tar` **or** `gzip` to unpack the archieve.

```
Available types: git, svn, hg, perforce, zip, rar, tar, gzip, phar, file.
```

The nodejs package obviously uses **both**.

How can I unpack `.tar.gz` packed files using composer?

I know I could use `post-update-cmd` and `post-install-cmd` commands and manually execute untar/gunzip, but that's not the way composer is ment to be.

Comment: Doesn't it use tar with the -z flag?

Comment: When using "tar", nothing gets unpacked, when I use "gzip", it does not untar.

Comment: 'tar' just installed and unpacked a tar.gz from google code archive fine for me.  good thing, too - no more repo access on google code and some projects have not yet moved elsewhere!

Comment: The same use-case to install the Ace editor via composer from https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/archive/v1.2.6.tar.gz

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The **"tar"** option understands both bare **`.tar`, `.tar.gz`, and even `.tar.bz2`** so just specify `"type": "tar"` and there is no need to specify the `"gz"`.  It figures out the decompression on it's own.

I ran into this issue, and was also initially confused, trying to auto-deploy a php app that used a proprietary library.  However I tried just "tar", it worked!  My `repositories` JSON part looks a little goofy because of the unusual structure of the tar archive, but it does work.  It looked something like this:

```
"repositories": [
  {
    "type": "package",
    "package": {
      "name": "RocketShipIt/RocketShipIt",
      "version": "1.4.9.3",
      "dist": {
        "url": "https://secret-deployment-server/RocketShipIt.tar.gz",
        "type": "tar"
      },
      "autoload": {
        "files": [
          "RocketShipIt/RocketShipIt.php"
        ],
        "psr-0": {
          "RocketShipIt\\": "RocketShipIt/RocketShipIt/RocketShipIt/"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

You can find, somewhat obscurely in the [Composer API documentation](https://getcomposer.org/apidoc/master/Composer/Downloader/TarDownloader.html) (not the end-user manual) that the `.tar`, `.tar.gz` and `.tar.bz2` are all three officially supported by `"type": "tar"`.  Apparently, it is handled internally by composer by the  `Composer\Downloader\TarDownloader` class.